# Is the metric function continuous in any topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I was trying to prove a result, and the question arose: is metrics a continuous function? Not enough, I wondered, the metric is continuous in which topology? In all topologies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$|d(x,y) -d(u,v)|\leq d(x,u) +d(y,v)$$ the metric is continuous in topology generated by itself and any other weaker topology.